# Batch: goto sections not working correctly

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that's not properly using the goto commands the way I want it to. Here's the batch itself (some comments and extra echo commands cut out to make it fit here better). I'll call this "`compile.bat`".

```dos
@echo off

set "consoleChoice=%~1"
goto consoleChoiceCheck
REM console not selected, main compiler prompt not used, pick console
:consoleChoicePrompt
CHOICE /C 12345 /M "Which console are you using? "
IF ERRORLEVEL 5 SET consoleChoice=XB & goto section2
IF ERRORLEVEL 4 SET consoleChoice=PSP & goto section2
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 SET consoleChoice=PS2 & goto section2
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 SET consoleChoice=GC & goto section2
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET consoleChoice=PC & goto modPackSection
REM Checks if console was selected from main compiler script/if main compiler script was used
:consoleChoiceCheck
if "%consoleChoice%"=="" goto consoleChoicePrompt

:modPackSection
REM get mod pack choice from main compiler script
set "modPackChoice=%~2"
goto modPackChoiceCheck
REM mod pack not selected, main compiler prompt not used, pick mod pack
:modPackChoicePrompt
CHOICE /C 1234 /M "Which Mod Pack are you using? "
IF ERRORLEVEL 4 SET modPackChoice=MUE & goto section2
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 SET modPackChoice=BHE & goto section2
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 SET modPackChoice=AXE & goto section2
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET modPackChoice=X2UP & goto section2
REM Checks if mod pack was selected from main compiler script/if main compiler script was used
:modPackChoiceCheck
if "%modPackChoice%"=="" goto modPackChoicePrompt

:section2
...
```

Here's the relevant code from the batch file that calls this one. I'll call this "`globalCompile.bat`"

```dos
CHOICE /C 12345 /M "Which console are you using? "
IF ERRORLEVEL 5 SET consoleChoice=XB & goto :skinPackSection
IF ERRORLEVEL 4 SET consoleChoice=PSP & goto :skinPackSection
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 SET consoleChoice=PS2 & goto :skinPackSection
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 SET consoleChoice=GC & goto :skinPackSection
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET consoleChoice=PC & goto :modPackSection

CHOICE /C 1234 /M "Which Mod Pack are you using? "
IF ERRORLEVEL 4 SET modPackChoice=MUE & goto skinPackSection
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 SET modPackChoice=BHE & goto skinPackSection
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 SET modPackChoice=AXE & goto skinPackSection
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET modPackChoice=X2UP & goto skinPackSection

...

if %consoleChoice%==PC (
    call compile.bat %consoleChoice% %modPackChoice%
) else (
    call compile.bat %consoleChoice%
)
```

As you can see, `compile.bat` is set up to run by being called from `globalCompile.bat`, but it can be run independently as well. Here's the issue:

- `compile.bat` runs correctly when called by itself. If you choose PC for `consoleChoice`, it will put up the prompt for `modPackChoice`. If you choose any other thing for consoleChoice, it will skip over that prompt.
- `globalCompile.bat` runs correctly when you choose the PC option in `globalCompile.bat`. It will ask for `modPackChoice`, and then run through and call all the respective batch files.
- `globalCompile.bat` messes up the execution of `compile.bat` if a non-PC option is chosen for `consoleChoice`. The `modPackChoice` prompt will not show up whenever I'm inputting things into `globalCompile.bat`, but once it starts calling the other batch files and gets to `compile.bat`, it will pull up `compile.bat`'s prompt for `modPackChoice`

I'm confused why this is happening, especially since it works fine on its own. Of all the batch files called by `globalCompile.bat`, `compile.bat` is the only one that uses a variable conditionally like this. I thought that setting up an if statement to only use the `modPackChoice` variable as an input for `compile.bat` if the PC option is selected, but that didn't work as you can see. Really, I feel like it should work without that because the `goto section2` command should skip over `:modPackSection` entirely. Can anyone help explain why this might be working only when called on its own?

Comment: If you choose an option other than PC, then the `global` routine goes to `skinpacksection` (not shown?) which appears to be the destination of each `modpack` choice, so it would appear that you are deliberately skipping `mod pack` in `global`

Comment: don't tag DOS here, this won't ever run in DOS. [Windows cmd are very different from DOS command.com](https://superuser.com/a/1411173/241386)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `global` calls `compile` with a non-pc choice made, then it supplies `compile` with only the first parameter.

Hence, `compile` will recognise `%~1`, ignore the `goto` in `:consoleChoiceCheck` as `consoleChoice` is not empty, and proceed to `:modPackSection`

`modPackChoice` will be set to *empty* as `%2` is not supplied, and therefore
`:modPackChoiceCheck` will execute `goto modPackChoicePrompt`

Comment: Ah, I knew my logic was off somewhere. So I’ll just have to give it a some non-empty value for `modPackChoice` if an option other than PC is selected and pass that in. Thank you!